# High Pitched Whine Sound from HDMI port2 speakers

Tags: sound, hdmi

My issue is that I am getting a high pitched noise from my speakers. When I connect my laptop to my Toshiba 32L2300U and then play any form of audio or dial the volume bar, I will hear a high pitched noise coming from my TV.

The high pitch sound persists and the only way to shut it off is to mute my TV not my laptop. When I boot my laptop to windows this problem does not occur. I found that this issue only occurs when I boot Ubuntu when connected to my TV.

I have tried turning the PCM output volume from merge to ignore and then rebooted the system but no change. I am not sure what the problem is, but I believe it is an ubuntu problem.
I also have version 18.04 of Ubuntu.
(edit: the noise does not happen when I use my laptop speakers, it only happens when I use my TV speakers)

Comment: I just noticed that last night with kernel update to `4.15.0-33` when sound should have gone to first TV (nVidia GTX970M controlled) but it went to second TV (Skylake Thunderbolt Intel HD 530 GPU controlled). I rebooted with `4.13.0-36` and life is back to normal :) In your case, reboot and select grub's **Advanced Options** submenu and select an older kernel. If you don't have any older kernels that work you can install one using this guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Comment: I just rebooted with 4.13.0-36. But that didn't resolve the issue. I still get the high pitch whine noise, but instead of a single beep. Its become a string of small high pitch noise, so like beep beeep beeeeeeep beep.

Comment: The problem could be my TV, as I do not hear a ringing sound when I connect my laptop to another TV; but the weird thing is that my TV only rings with ubuntu booted and not windows booted

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it was only `4.15.0-33` kernel but yesterday I noticed it briefly in Windows 10 too. Again it happened on the secondary TV When signing in via Chrome to a password enabled website.

Then today under Kernel 4.13.0-36 I noticed system notification sound for volume change (that popping bubble sound) was coming from second TV driven by Intel HD 530 over USB-C Thunderbolt Display Port to HDMI converter whilst real sound internet video / news channels were coming from main TV driven by nVidia.

So I did a quick screenshot so you could see the setup:

[image: App sound to nVidia and system sound to intel.png]

I am using a special kernel module for nVidia sound due to newer Dell Laptops powering off the sound card in newer nVidia Cards to save 5 watts of electricity: https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda (not the exact github link but close enough).

Hopefully this helps. If not yourself then others at least.

Comment: Not sure what to do, but some notes I wanted to add, I run a lenovo x260 with a soundcard of HDA Intel PCH. I also noticed that the ringing from my TV also plays when I using my headphones as the output. A single beeping sound can be heard every time I adjust the volume until it just become a continuous beeping/ringing sound, which is very annoying. But are you suggesting that I change my sound card?